# PHP string replace tabs with spaces NOT using regex

Tags: php, replace

How do I use `str_replace` to replace tabs with spaces in PHP? I need to do so without using regular expressions.

```
$find = array('');//use what here?
$replace = array(' ');
$string = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
```

Comment: `chr(9)` is also a tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for a tab character in PHP (as it is in many other languages) is `\t`. Try this:

```
$find = array("\t");
$replace = array(' ');
$string = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
```

Comment: The person with the rainbow colored unicorn avatar wins by posting the working answer first, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try-

```
$string = str_replace("\t", " ", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `\t` string. Usually you can use these special control characters with the backslash, such as `\n` for "line feed", `\r` for "carriage return", etc. This is true for most of the common programming languages.

```
$find = array("\t"); //use \t here!
$replace = array(' ');
$string = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);
```